# A-Frame camera rotation using lookAt()

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

Word up SO,

I'm trying to pull together something akin to an 'anchor look' component in A-Frame – the idea was supposed to be like a combination of **aframe-href-component** and **aframe-look-at-component**, where clicking a link to an anchor (`<a href="#anchor">Link</a>`) would make the camera "look at" the entity whose `id=""` matches the anchor.

I thought I had a working concept just by modifying the look-at component a bit, i.e. poll for hash updates and `Object3D.lookAt()` the anchor, but there seems to be a problem I wasn't accounting for that probably comes from my poor understanding of Euler/quaternion/etc:

When the camera's rotation gets updated by `lookAt()`, it seems to lose its previous rotational reference – dragging the camera has strange rotation results, and the results get stranger the more you've rotated the camera *before* calling `lookAt()`.

I've set up a basic codepen at http://codepen.io/wosevision/pen/JWRMyK containing my version of the component to demonstrate; what is causing this and what is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You know the perspective camera nested in a group, when you drag the mouse to change the rotation, the group rotation changed, but the perspective camera didn't. the rotation would be strange if the perspective camera rotation is not `(0,0,0)`.

It's very hard to set camera rotation, If you really want to do that, you need to look deep int the implementation of camera control and modify.